# Invalid type argument of unary '*' (have int?

Tags: c, int, unary-operator

I have read other questions like this but none seemed to work...
My code is:

```
int flowRateFormula(int pipeDiameter,double velocity)
{
int integer3;

integer3=PI*(1/4)*(pow(pipeDiameter,2))*velocity;

return integer3;

 }
```

And the error is:

```
flowRate.c: In function ‘flowRateFormula’:
flowRate.c:38:13: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

What to do?
BTW PI IS DEFINED

Comment: Is PI defined? I'm betting it's empty. BTW, `(1/4)` will give you zero, making your whole expression zero.

Comment: Integer division: `1/4`... Change it to `1.0/4.0`

Comment: @FredLarson: I think you are right, It compiles fine for me if PI is defined.

Comment: (Unrelated): Either replace `(1/4)` with `0.25` or `(1/4.0)`.

Comment: You are mixing types here, pow returns double.  (1/4) with int type == 0.  You probably want to do all of your calculation with doubles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you have the line

```
#define PI
```

somewhere, which causes your code to be equivalent to:

```
integer3=*(1/4)*....
```

and this fails to compile. Replace it with e.g.

```
#define PI 3.1416
```

Note also that `(1/4)` will be evaluated to 0, because integer division returns an integer. you probably want to use `1.0/4.0`.

Comment: Better replace with #define PI (3.1416)

Comment: @buddhabrot: That's good practice in general, but I don't think it matters here since it only contains a single number so operator precedence won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a value for PI first.

Answer (score 0):

Is PI defined? I'm betting it's empty. BTW, (1/4) will give you zero, making your whole expression zero.